# How to add setAttributes with looping new Option

Tags: javascript

Hello is anybody knows how to add setAttributes with looping new Option

this is my code

```
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
var value = i ; 
var price = i*5;

select1.options.add(new Option(price, value));
}
```

and my goal is adding another custom attribute using setAttribute to each of the option like this

```
<select id="select1">
   <option value="1" optionNo="option1">5</option>
   <option value="2" optionNo="option2">10</option>
</select>
```

can anybody help me with these problem thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create DOM object of `option` and use `setAttribute` method to add your custom attribute, see below:

```js
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
var value = i ; 
var price = i*5;
var opt = document.createElement("option");
opt.value = value;
opt.text = price;
opt.setAttribute('optionNo','option'+value);
select1.options.add(opt);
}
```

```html
<select id="select1">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to get reference of select and use append

```js
const select = document.getElementById("select1")
select.append(new Option("option3", 3))
console.dir(select.options)
```

```html
<select id="select1">
  <option value="1" optionNo="option1">5</option>
  <option value="2" optionNo="option2">10</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I think you can use**

```
for (value = 0; value < 20; value++) {
   var price = value*5;
   var option = new Option(price, value);
   option.setAttribute('optionNo','option'+value);
   select1.options.add(option);
}
```